# Security in simple php mailer

Tags: php, forms, security, email, spam

I'm trying to add a php mailer to my ultra simple website. I don't even have any databases there. I want to add simple spam-filter, for eg. "Is it a spam? Answer NO: [     ]". Would it be sufficient level of security? Or should I add something more? As I said - very, very simple page with low number of visitors.

Comment: `<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { do mailer} else {die('direct access not allowed');} ?>` also, a math equation that the user should answer and some javascript to generate a random equation and answer combination. Also, check if each field isset if you need validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it really simple you could use the hidden spam filter technique, this has the added benefit of not adding large obtrusive filter questions to your form.

Basically, add a form field of type text within a div on the site, and place it within a div which you hide using css.

Ensure that you name the field something like 'spam-filter' or 'anti-spam'.

Then, when processing the form check if the field is filled in, if it is chances are it's a bot of some kind, as they will auto fill fields, and the better ones check for fields such as this..... either way, as users can't see the field, anything that fills it in will be automated.

I use this technique and it performs exactly as you would expect.

Example....

```
<style>
#hide-me {
display: none;
}
</style>
<span id="hide-me"><input type="text" value="" name="anti-spam"></span>
```

Obviously there are a few really good actual anti-spam scripts out there, but when you need something simple or unobtrusive, you can't go wrong with this.

Comment: Not bad at all. I wonder though, if using a hidden field would also produce the same result?

Comment: A lot of bots ignore hidden fields, as they see them as 'hidden from user, hidden from use'. However, hiding by css seems to snag them. Another enhancement is to hide the span using js/jquery, that way the hidden css status is harder to detect for the better bot scripters out there ;)

Comment: You have a point there. There's always a way to "outfox" the fox *as it were*, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For adding simple security, consider taking a look at the [catcha library](https://github.com/mynetx/catcha).

Answer (score 0):

While a simple "Is it a spam" question will prevent a generic bot from using the form, it will be trivially easy to create a script to abuse the form. With a quick glance at the form's source code will reveal that a potential abuser would just need to add a new field "is-it-spam=no" to their code.

If you're looking for the easiest implementation, I'd recommend [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) or a hosted form service

For ReCaptcha, there are classes available for most popular programming languages, and it's used really widely. ReCaptcha will provide you with a private key that you keep secure in your code, and a public key that would show in the source code of the website. ReCaptcha then uses information you submit using your private key to assure that anyone who submits the form did so based on the image on your website without writing a super-simply script to abuse the form.

If you're open to using a hosted service, you check out a solution like [WuFoo](http://www.wufoo.com) (or see [this blog post](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2010/07/08/free-contact-form-services/) for more ideas). A hosted service will handle all the security and filtering for you, and you only need to insert a small snippet of code in your site to embed their service.